# How to add space between character-number and capital-lowercase (vice-versa)?

Tags: java

I'm currently doing a program for a school project and programming is not my strong subject especially after covid hit. The difficulty I am currently having is figuring out an efficient way to display a string from a text file.

I am currently using the FileReader to read the file:

e.g. A text file contains the data 34QueensDrive

Do I have to use a chars Array to create a space between the integers and capital letters or is there a better way?

Comment: Why did you revert my edit? Was that not your desired behavior?

Comment: This should work `text = re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", text)`

Comment: The best way, especially for someone who wants to learn something, would be to first try to solve it yourself, building on what you already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `char` type is obsolete

The [Answer by Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67220790/642706) is nearly there, except that the `char` type is obsolete. That type cannot represent even half of the characters defined by [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and supported by Java.

## Code points

Instead, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers. Unicode uses a range of just over a million to assign a number to each of its 143,859 characters.

For example:

- `A` = 65 = LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
- `♫` = 9,835 = BEAMED EIGHTH NOTES
- = 128,567 = FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK

### Better var names

Also, I suggest using variable names that are more simple and clear.

### Digits following text

And we need to add another test. For an input such as `W34QueensDrive` with digits following letters, we need this third test:

```
( ! Character.isDigit( previousCodePoint ) && Character.isDigit( codePoint ) )
```

### Example code

Here is the code seen in that [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67220790/642706) but modified to use code points rather than `char` type.

```java
// Modified form of code written by Spectric at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67220790/642706

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String s = "W34QueensDrive";  //  "34QueensDrive";
int[] codePoints = s.codePoints().toArray();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < codePoints.length ; i++ )
{
    int codePoint = codePoints[ i ];
    if ( i != 0 )
    {
        int previousCodePoint = codePoints[ i - 1 ];
        if (
                ( ! Character.isDigit( previousCodePoint ) && Character.isDigit( codePoint ) )
                        ||
                        ( Character.isDigit( previousCodePoint ) && ! Character.isDigit( codePoint ) )
                        ||
                        ( Character.isLowerCase( previousCodePoint ) && Character.isUpperCase( codePoint ) )
        )
        {
            stringBuilder.append( " " );
        }
        stringBuilder.appendCodePoint( codePoint );
    } else
    {
        stringBuilder.appendCodePoint( codePoint );
    }
}
String result = stringBuilder.toString();

System.out.println( result );
```

When run.

> 34 Queens Drive

Depending on the language of your data, you might also test for [titlecase letters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Lt) by calling [`Character.isTitleCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isTitleCase(int)).

---

For background info, read [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: This information was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex solution:

```
String s = "34QueensDrive";
int len = s.length();
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  char cur = s.charAt(i);
  if (i != 0) {
    char b4 = s.charAt(i - 1);
    if ((Character.isDigit(b4) && !Character.isDigit(cur)) || (Character.isLowerCase(b4) && Character.isUpperCase(cur))) {
      newString.append(" ");
    }
    newString.append(cur);
  } else {
    newString.append(cur);
  }
}
System.out.println(newString.toString());
```

Test Runs:

```
34QueensDrive = 34 Queens Drive
34QueensDriveAvenue = 34 Queens Drive Avenue
```